# MacOs cli: unexpected ls behavior

Tags: mac-osx

I've sort of "lost" some files under a hidden directory in my home called .node_libraries When I ls its content from another directory, i see the wanted files and directories, but when i cd to it and then list the content, i can only see one directory. See below:

```
marvin:lib gu$ pwd
/Users/gu/dev/node.js/express/lib
marvin:lib gu$ ls ../../../../.node_libraries/
admin.js      crypto        gridfs        request.js    view.js
bson          cursor.js     index.js      response.js
collection.js db.js         jade          responses
commands      express       middleware    server.js
connection.js goog          public        utils.js
marvin:lib gu$ cd ../../../../.node_libraries/
marvin:.node_libraries gu$ ls
connect
```

What could be going on? Thanks

Comment: Dennis’ answer seems right. The *cd* and *pwd* commands built into *bash* conspire to give the illusion of being able to *cd* into and out of symlinks; *ls* is an external program and can not be easily recruited into the conspiracy. When *ls* resolves `..`, it uses the “physical” cwd. The shell’s *pwd* shows (and *cd* uses) the “logical” cwd. If one of the path components of `dev/node.js/express/lib` (under `/Users/gu`) is a symlink, then the physical and logical cwds will not match. Use `set -P` (or `cd -P` and `pwd -P`/`/bin/pwd`) to escape the “symlink-in-cwd conspiracy”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a symlinked directory.

What do these commands give you?:

```
set -o | grep physical
alias cd
alias ls
ls -ld /Users/gu/.node_libraries
ls -ld /Users/gu/dev/node.js/express/lib
find /Users/gu -H -type l -xtype d -ls
```